# String interpolation with triple quotes and multiple lines

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I'm getting stange results from triple `"""` quoted strings when using string interpolation and line breaks:

```
val foo = "bar"

s"""$foo"""
```

This is ok.

```
s"""
$foo
"""
```

This is wrong, I get the following output:

```
"
bar
"
```

Why the heck are there quotation marks?

Comment: Isn't it just a `"\nbar\n"`?

Comment: Why do you think it is interpolation issue? `"""
     | bar
     | """` (multilined) will give you exactly the same result (leading and trailing `\n` which REPL encloses in quotes)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is just the REPL surrounding multi-line strings in quotation marks. You'll find the actual string contains no quotation marks:

```
res0.contains("\"")
res1 : Boolean = false
```

Comment: Ah, of course. It seems the REPL prints extra quotation marks for string results when they span multiple lines. (For whatever reason). Thanks

Comment: @0__ The REPL prints quotation marks when strings are surrounded by whitespace, which makes totally sense in order to see where a string starts and ends.

Comment: It would me more consistent to *always* print quotation marks, unless you are using println on the string.